# Watin times out when using SignalR

Tags: watin, signalr

We are using Watin extensively for our acceptance-tests, and we are now starting to experience problems when introducing SignalR into our web pages. We are getting timeouts for things like "Button.Click" and "WebBrowser.GoTo", functions which worked perfect before. We are getting a "Timeout while Internet Explorer busy" exception from Watin and I am guessing this occurs because SignalR is polling from the client (this will probably work a lot better when WebSockets arrive). Does anyone know of a workaround for this?

Comment: Probably receiving of data using SignalR is done through long polling in blocking way in same thread as session logic is processed. Thats why it might block other logic due to waiting for receiving data and blocking thread on that point. If there is way to receive data asynchronously - that might be a thing to look into.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Any solutions?

Comment: I'm using IE10 on Windows 8 with Dot Net 4.0 and having the same issue. WatiN site doesn't say that they support IE10, but, it seems like, WatiN works fine on IE10 as long as the page doesn't use SignalR. One solution to the issue that I'm planning to try out is [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/). WatinN works only with IE(and some old versions of Firefox which we can't find now) but Selenium works with IE, Firefox and Chrome. I'm going to use Selenium with Chrome or Firefox as I just need to automate my UI tests.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not an expert with SignalR but I work for a company who produces a commercial implementation called [WebSync](http://www.frozenmountain.com/products/websync).

My initial suspicion is that you might be hitting the concurrent requests limit for IE.

First, does the same test work fine in Firefox, but not IE? (IE is usually worse than other browsers with concurrent requests). Also what version of IE is being tested? The concurrent requests limit is different for different generations of browsers. Take a look at this [article documenting the concurrent request limits for IE](http://weblogs.asp.net/mschwarz/archive/2008/07/21/internet-explorer-8-and-maximum-concurrent-connections.aspx). In IE this limit can even affect multiple copies of the same page open in different windows. But it depends on version of IE, Microsoft has been improving steadily over time.

In some cases IE will be operating with only 2 concurrent requests per domain! It might be worth opening the developer tools in your browser and monitoring the active HttpRequests in progress. You'll see a long-polling request for SignalR, but see if their is any other frequent AJAX activity possibly blocking the second available request slot. (Maybe something else totally unrelated to SignalR that is also making AJAX requests? Or maybe a slow loading resource like a bloated CSS or JS file?)

For WebSync we fix this problem by moving websync onto a subdomain like "stream.mydomain.com". Now your page resources are still on "www.mydomain.com" so even in the worst case scenario IE can have 2 concurrent requests to "www." and 2 concurrent requests to "stream.". If you're site is really massive we can even further divide the subdomain by using "a.stream.mydomain.com", "b.stream.mydomain.com", .... "z.stream.mydomain.com" which can alleviate the problem further if the end user is likely to open the page in multiple browser windows (each windows pointing to same domain).

If you can't move your long-polling connection some people move other stuff like images, stylesheets and javascript to a separate domain like "static.mydomain.com" so that those requests go somewhere else.

Comment: We are working with IE9 not tried Firefox. I know signal-r also has issues running on an iPad right now, and I wonder if its the same issue. Thanks for the other info, going dig into it:-)